# Code in display function running twice, once before and after submitted

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

As the title says, I am having an issue with a display function executing code twice. I am confused to why it runs the function after a user has submitted a form via post.

What I wan't the code to do is run once, and then when the user submits the form for the code underneath the `if request.method == "POST":` to run.

For instance if I was writing a route for my website and had the following code:

```
@app.route("/example", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def example():
    #do some stuff beforehand ONCE
    if request.method == "POST":
       # do other stuff after the stuff above
```

What I would like is what the comments say, but instead it looks more like this:

```
@app.route("/example", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def example():
    #do some stuff beforehand but TWICE
    if request.method == "POST":
       # do other stuff after the stuff above
```

The biggest issue here is that the code that comes above the `if request.method == "POST":` modifies an external value which means that it gets changed twice, even if I put it into a local variable.

Here is what I am currently running:

```
@app.route("/displayOptions", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def displayOptions():
    """ display options for selling a stock if multiple occur """
    stocks = session["identicalStocks"]
    shares = session["shares"]
    ticker = session["ticker"]
    soldStocks = db.execute("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE stock_sold IS NOT NULL AND id = :ID", ID = session["user_id"])

    for stock in stocks:
        print(stock)
        for soldStock in soldStocks:
            if stock["transaction_number"] == soldStock["stock_sold"]:
                stock["shares"] += soldStock["shares"]

    if request.method == "POST":
        # ensure transaction number is an integer
        try:
            transactionNumber = int(request.form.get("transactionNumber"))
        except ValueError:
            return apology("Invalid transaction number")

        validTransactionNumber = False
        # ensure transaction number is correct
        for stock in stocks:
            if stock["transaction_number"] == transactionNumber:
                stockSelected = stock
                validTransactionNumber = True
                break

        if validTransactionNumber == False:
            return apology("Invalid transaction number")

        sellStock(stockSelected)

        # ensure there are a proper amount of shares to sell
        if stockSelected["shares"] < shares:
            return apology("Not enough shares to sell")

        return redirect(url_for("index"))

    return render_template("displayOptions.html", stocks = stocks)
```

The website also restarts with stat.

Comment: `displayOptions` is (presumably) executed twice: once when the page is fetched with `GET`, and again when the user submits a `POST`.  If you have code that should only execute in one of those cases, put it underneath an `if` statement checking for a specific method.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: You can even write two functions. Decorate them with `@app.route("/example", methods=["GET"])` and `@app.route("/example", methods=["POST"])`. Just make sure you are not using the same function name twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks John Gordon with providing the answer to this question!

How to fix:

```
@app.route("/example", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def example():
    if request.method == "POST":
        #do some stuff beforehand ONCE
    if request.method == "POST":
       # do other stuff after the stuff above
```